# renaming printers on network

Tags: network-printer, shared-printers

I want to rename all the printers within a network but if I rename it on the server the clients don't see it, if I rename it on the client others don't see it. Is there anyway to manage this with minimum effort like a good admin should?

Domain is server 2003 with windows xp clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about a single print server and not any locally attached printers.

I executed a similar conversion a few years ago - a login script that removes all the printer mappings and recreates them on the client side combined with a renaming the printers one at a time is the route we went. It caused very little disruption. I also took advantage of the time to set up security groups for the printers.

EDIT - you can also use Group Policy Preferences to remove and create new printers.

Comment: tried a vbs script but didnt work, also tried NET USER etc but didnt work. Used rundll to map them and it worked fine. rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "\\servername\printer name"